# Connect nodes at same level using constant extra space

Tags: algorithm, tree, time-complexity

Objective:To write a function to connect all the adjacent nodes at the same level in a binary tree. Structure of the given Binary Tree node is like following.

```
struct node{
  int data;
  struct node* left;
  struct node* right;
  struct node* nextRight;  
}
```

Initially, all the nextRight pointers point to garbage values. Function should set these pointers to point next right for each node.

Solution:

```
void connectRecur(struct node* p);
struct node *getNextRight(struct node *p);

// Sets the nextRight of root and calls connectRecur() for other nodes
void connect (struct node *p)
{
    // Set the nextRight for root
    p->nextRight = NULL;

    // Set the next right for rest of the nodes (other than root)
    connectRecur(p);
}

/* Set next right of all descendents of p. This function makes sure that
nextRight of nodes ar level i is set before level i+1 nodes. */
void connectRecur(struct node* p)
{
    // Base case
    if (!p)
       return;

    /* Before setting nextRight of left and right children, set nextRight
    of children of other nodes at same level (because we can access 
    children of other nodes using p's nextRight only) */
    if (p->nextRight != NULL)
       connectRecur(p->nextRight);

    /* Set the nextRight pointer for p's left child */
    if (p->left)
    {
       if (p->right)
       {
           p->left->nextRight = p->right;
           p->right->nextRight = getNextRight(p);
       }
       else
           p->left->nextRight = getNextRight(p);

       /* Recursively call for next level nodes.  Note that we call only
       for left child. The call for left child will call for right child */
       connectRecur(p->left);
    }

    /* If left child is NULL then first node of next level will either be
      p->right or getNextRight(p) */
    else if (p->right)
    {
        p->right->nextRight = getNextRight(p);
        connectRecur(p->right);
    }
    else
       connectRecur(getNextRight(p));
}

/* This function returns the leftmost child of nodes at the same level as p.
   This function is used to getNExt right of p's right child
   If right child of p is NULL then this can also be used for the left child */
struct node *getNextRight(struct node *p)
{
    struct node *temp = p->nextRight;

    /* Traverse nodes at p's level and find and return
       the first node's first child */
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        if(temp->left != NULL)
            return temp->left;
        if(temp->right != NULL)
            return temp->right;
        temp = temp->nextRight;
    }

    // If all the nodes at p's level are leaf nodes then return NULL
    return NULL;
}
```

**What will be the time complexity of this solution?**

Comment: Can you explain how did u come to this conclusion?

Comment: see my answer for the explanation.

Comment: While comments are nice and all, that's a fair amount of code to go through. You may want to learn how to write [pseudo-code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_code) and/or write a sufficiently detailed high-level description.

Comment: Kindly approve the correct answer for there are 2 different answers.

Comment: I provided an answer to a similar question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66269648/9347459)

Answer (score 1):

It is O(n^2) because of the getNextRight.

Easiest to see is to consider you have a complete binary tree. The number of leafs is O(n/2) so O(n). You get to call getNextRight for each leaf.

The first getNextRight is going to be for the last leaf on the right. That takes no passes through the while loop.

Next, you call getNextRight for the next to last leaf on the right. That takes 1 pass through the while loop.

For the next leaf you get 2 passes through the while loop. And so on... you get O(1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n/2) which is O(n^2).

Also the space complexity is not really constant. It is O(log n) if the tree is balanced because of the recursion. You may have a log n sized stack. If the tree is not balanced it will be even worst.

Answer (score 0):

What appears to me is that you are connecting the nodes level-wise starting from the root node.

At any level since the parents have already been connected, you simply reach out to the next branch through the parents. Hence you are accessing each node only once (or twice through a child) at most.

Hence to me, the order of time complexity seems to be O(n) where n is the total number of elements in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

I provided an answer to a similar question here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66269648/9347459), using level-order traversal. Space and time complexity is O(n)