# Populating Next Right Pointers in Each Node of a binary tree

Tags: c, tree, queue, tree-traversal

I am trying to do [this problem on Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/populating-next-right-pointers-in-each-node-ii/) in C.

Given the following binary tree,

```
     1
   /  \
  2    3
 / \    \
4   5    7
```

After calling your function, the tree should look like:

```
     1 -> NULL
   /  \
  2 -> 3 -> NULL
 / \    \
4-> 5 -> 7 -> NULL
```

What I am doing is creating a queue for Level Order Traversal of the tree
and joining the next pointer of each node to the next queue node at each 
level. To separate levels, I am enqueuing NULL pointer.

So for above example:: the queue is ->
[1,#, 2,3,#,4,5,7,#] where # is NULL ptr.

Here is my code for the problem::

```
/**
 * Definition for binary tree with next pointer.
 * struct TreeLinkNode {
 *  int val;
 *  struct TreeLinkNode *left, *right, *next;
 * };
 *
 */
bool isEmpty(int start,int end){
    if(start > end)
        return true;
    return false;
}

void connect(struct TreeLinkNode *root) {
    if(!root || (!root->left && !root->right))
        return;
    int cap = 1000;
    struct TreeLinkNode** q = malloc(cap* sizeof(struct TreeLinkNode*));
    int start=0, end=-1, curLevel=1, nextLevel=0;
    // enqueue
    q[++end] = root;
    while(isEmpty(start, end) == false){
        //dequeue
        struct TreeLinkNode* temp = q[start++];
        curLevel--;
        if(isEmpty(start, end) == false && curLevel !=0)
            temp->next = q[start];
        if(temp->left){
            q[++end] = temp->left;
            nextLevel++;
        }
        if(temp->right){
            q[++end] = temp->right;
            nextLevel++;
        }
        if(curLevel ==0){
            curLevel = nextLevel;
            nextLevel =0;
        }
        if(start> cap-50 || end> cap-50)
            q = realloc(q, 2*cap*sizeof(struct TreeLinkNode *));
    }
    free(q);
}
```

the code is apparently working for small test cases but for larger ones on Leetcode the code gives runtime errors.
I dont know what i am doing wrong.
Please help. I would really appreciate if someone could run this code on Leetcode

Comment: According to what you wrote, it seems that you are queuing the NULL pointer too often : it should be after each level but in your code it is after each analyzed node.

Comment: You are right. To solve this problem I made few changes. But still the code  is not working.

Comment: And yes thanks for pointing out the mistake

Answer (score 0):

The end of a level occurs when your analyze the last node of the previous level. Since each level ends with a NULL in `q`, when `temp` is NULL it means the full level has been analyzed and you can end the next level by inserting NULL.

So I made little modifications to your code :

```
void connect(struct TreeLinkNode *root) {
    int cap = 1000;
    struct TreeLinkNode** q = malloc(cap* sizeof(struct TreeLinkNode*));
    int start=0, end=-1;
    // enqueue
    q[++end] = root;
    q[++end] = NULL; // End of first level
    for (;;) {
        //dequeue
        struct TreeLinkNode* temp = q[start++];
        if (temp == NULL) {
            if (q[start] == NULL) // Two consecutives NULL means end of tree
                break;
            q[++end] = NULL; // End of level
        } else {
            temp->next = q[start];
            if(temp->left)
                q[++end] = temp->left;
            if(temp->right)
                q[++end] = temp->right;
            if (end > cap-50) { // end is always greater or equal to start
                q = realloc(q, 2*cap*sizeof(struct TreeLinkNode *));
            }
        }
    }
    free(q);
}
```

I can't test it in real right now so it may not work directly, it is mainly for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would be providing my result in `javascript`, but I would provide enough explanation on the steps to reproduce this in another language:

1. Approach this problem using `level order traversal (breadth-first search)`.
2. Check if the provided root is null, if it is, we return it immediately
3. Create a `queue` that we would be using to store our binary tree nodes
4. Push the root into the queue
5. Start a while loop that would run only when there are items in the queue
6. Get the length of the queue and store it in a variable e.g. `queueLength`
7. loop through the length of the queue (`queueLength`) while observing the current index of the loop;
8. Shift/Remove the item on `index 0` in the `queue` and save it as `currValue`
9. Check if it has a left node first, push it into the queue if it does
10. Check if it has a node value also, push it into the queue if it does
11. If the value of the index in the loop is not equal to `queueLength-1`, `currValue.next` would be equal to `queue[0]` i.e. the first item on the queue.
12. If the value of the index in the loop is equal to `queueLength-1`, then this is the last node on this level, we can set it's next value to `null`
13. The while loop would repeat `step 6 - 12` again.

```
const connect = function (root) {
    let queue = [];
    
    if(root){
        queue.push(root);
    }

    while (queue.length) {
        // let curr = queue.shift(1);
        const queueLength = queue.length;

        for (let i = 0; i < queueLength; i++) {
            const currValue = queue.shift(0);
            if (currValue.left) {
                queue.push(currValue.left);
            }

            if (currValue.right) {
                queue.push(currValue.right);
            }

            if (i !== queueLength - 1) {
                currValue.next = queue[0];
            }

            if (i === queueLength - 1) {
                currValue.next = null;
            }
        }
    }

    return root;
};
```